# Store variable in Azure logic app to use in next run

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, api-design, azure-log-analytics, azure-sentinel

I'm fetching data from API, but I want to fetch data from the last time when logic run app to current time (to reduce redundancy). So where can I store the last date-time so I can use it in API? API provide that feature to pass time but in azure logic app where can I store last date information?

Current logic app design

[image: Logic App Designer]

Comment: Could you elaborate on the requirement?? Looks like you need a bit of caching in your solution. What redundancy are you referring to?

Comment: consider I call API 10 hours ago so now I have data.After 2 to 3 hours I again call API but rather than getting all the data I only want the difference of data. Now API provide that feature to pass timestamp but somewhere in logic APP I have to save last time when logic app is run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now logic app doesn't support such variable could be shared in different runs.

So if you want to implement this feature, you could use azure storage queue or service bus to do it, create a message to store value you want to use in next run. And every time after getting the value remember to delete the  original data, also do put message action to store new data to queue or service bus.

Hope this could help you, if you still have other problem please feel free to let me know.

Comment: can you please provide me a guide on how to use blob storage in this scenario. First I have to initialize blob storage and in the last, I have to update with the current time.

Comment: Please provide more information, so you just want to update a blob content with the current time, and what you want to store to use in next run.

Comment: Currently, I'm doing this way
- Get blob content and initialize two-variable From and To
- if the file content is not set(If the first-time run) then just update variable To with current time otherwise take a blob data into From variable and update To variable with the current time

Comment: So did you get any problem, suppose you already how to design this flow.

Comment: @UtsavPatel is the blob method working fine? I've used this for creating PDFs before with lots of a data and I've noticed that with a large volume blobs have acted a little sporadic. Do you see that with this variable?

Comment: hey @JonWalzer, If I remember correctly, we kept the blob method only, and it was working fine, though in our case it was only about storing one variable.

Comment: @UtsavPatel, I've also implemented this solution and it is working well.

Answer (score 2):

You need to persist variables externally. You could use a blob storage like in the blog post bellow.

Try this, it was helpful to me:
[azure-logic-apps-storing-variables-between-runs](https://sysadmin-central.com/2021/01/04/azure-logic-apps-storing-variables-between-runs/)